# How to create a wavy beam?

Tags: unity, 2d, godot, effect

I want to implement a wavy laser beam similar to the Proton Backpack in Enter the Gungeon.

https://youtu.be/wl-o6gbMqFM?t=58

It's easy enough to draw a line from one point to another, but how to get the undulating curviness and the lighting effects?

I am working in Godot, but I could easily adapt techniques from Unity, if you know them, since Godot has similar resources.

I asked a version of this question in a Godot forum, but am also asking it here

Comment: Does Godot have an equivalent to the Unity [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)?

Comment: @Philipp, yes it does. And if the methods are slightly different, I can always write my own.

Comment: This Proton Backpack is a stream, like the youtuber said.
Think about several gunshots, with a line drawed between them, its almost the same thing. The curviness can be achieved with some 2d-curve algorithm like bezier curve, and take care with cuve continuity

Comment: @648trindade with a tiny bit more detail, that's an answer I'd upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique is the following.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best method, but you could emit particles like a regular gun and draw a curved line between them, give them a certain lifespan and then apply shaders to the lines.